# Unable to get my webpage height in javascript?

Tags: javascript

I have a different problem , when user clicks on page and dragging to some location, then with that co-ordinates i should draw a rectangle div...

But it working fine, when user doesn't scroll the window..

If he scroll the window. then he trying to creating a rectangle means ,then it is coming to upper positions..

how can i solve this problem.. i don't have much knowledge on javascript..

If i could not explain you in detail. feel free to ask me..

thanks 
Rajesh

Comment: No i am using javascript..? when user clicks on browsers some location like if he clicks on 300, i should get the scrolled length, i should add/substract and set a div....

Comment: Simon Hartigan , can you help on this , how can i get scrolled height in javascript

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you are missing the scroll position start and end point. On the mousedown event get the scroll position then on the mouseup event get the scroll position. Use the change in scroll position to help determine the size of your div.

On each event get the scroll position with a function like this:

```
function getScrollXY() {
  var scrOfX = 0, scrOfY = 0;
  if( typeof( window.pageYOffset ) == 'number' ) {
    //Netscape compliant
    scrOfY = window.pageYOffset;
    scrOfX = window.pageXOffset;
  } else if( document.body && ( document.body.scrollLeft || document.body.scrollTop ) ) {
    //DOM compliant
    scrOfY = document.body.scrollTop;
    scrOfX = document.body.scrollLeft;
  } else if( document.documentElement && ( document.documentElement.scrollLeft || document.documentElement.scrollTop ) ) {
    //IE6 standards compliant mode
    scrOfY = document.documentElement.scrollTop;
    scrOfX = document.documentElement.scrollLeft;
  }
  return [ scrOfX, scrOfY ];
}
```